# JQuery simple tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm looking for some JQuery tooltip plugin or even a simple solution to show a dynamic value from an input field when I mouse over a determined link (text or image)

I've tried a lot of plugins but none can give me the dynamic value of the field.

Example:

Input field:
`input type="text" name="example" id="example" value=""`

Link for mouseover/tooltip:

`a href="#" id="tooltip">value</a`

The value of the input field will be changed by another JQuery function and it's working
fine, but when I try to show it's value using any tooltip plugin, doesn't work.

If I simple use the alert() function, it's working fine.

I don't need any fancy tooltip, only show the value of the input field.

Please, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

We use [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) for our tooltips on twitter.com, and it works great.  It can generate the tooltip text dynamically using a callback function, like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="example" value="foo" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#example").tipsy({
  title: function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }
});
```

Here's a [complete example/demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TDAYw/).  There are plenty of configuration options to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

look on this library

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html